# How are cbind and rbind implemented?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`, and I want to `cbind` them:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(c=c(3,4), d=c(5,7))
df1 <- cbind(df1,df2)
```

When I write the line 3 this way, would R create a new larger data frame and assign it to `df1` or it would optimized to add the new columns of `df2` into `df1` in place to save memory? Are there any documents on this?

Comment: Does `tracemem` help you out at all?

Comment: Suggested read: [Advanced R: Memory usage](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

Comment: In short: It would create a copy. If you want to avoid this behavior, check the `data.table` package

Comment: Thank you guys, all suggestions are helpful

Answer (score 1):

A data frame is a vector of columns. R will create a new vector for the new df1 result. Earlier versions would also duplicate the columns, but as of 3.1.0 R no longer does this and the columns will be shared between the new df1 and the old df1 and df2.